# Tappable zone for UIImageView with rounded corners UIKit

Tags: swift, uikit, uiimage, uigesturerecognizer

I've got an interesting problem - there's a square UIImageView with rounded corners (which make it a circle), i made it so whenever you touch the view something happens, but the problem is that the zone outside the circle and inside the frame of a view is still tappable and i have no idea how to fix it.

To be clear i want my view to only be tappable inside the circle. Is there a way to do so?

Here's my code snippet:

```swift
    @IBOutlet weak var profilePictureView: UIImageView? //it is 240x240

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        profilePictureView?.layer.cornerRadius = 240 / 2
        
        let tap = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(handleProfilePictureTap(_:)))
        profilePictureView?.addGestureRecognizer(tap)
        profilePictureView?.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
    }
```

Comment: Certainly. You just have to override `hitTest`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assign the view controller as the delegate of the recognizer, and filter the touches the recognizer receives:

```
func viewDidLoad() {
    ...
    tap.delegate = self
}

func gestureRecognizer(_ gr: UIGestureRecognizer, shouldReceive touch: UITouch) -> Bool {
    let bezierPath = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: profilePictureView.bounds, cornerRadius: profilePictureView.layer.cornerRadius)
    let point = touch.location(in: profilePictureView)
    return bezierPath.contains(point)
}
```